# Use jquery cookie to keep CSS height

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I have a button which sets a CSS height which I need to keep the same even after page refreshes. Here is the code:

```
<script>
   function changeHeight(){
       $('#totalInfo').css('marginTop', '172px'); 
       $('.single #secondary-two #cart').css('maxHeight', '290px');
   }
</script>

<button onClick="changeHeight()">Change Height</button>
```

The problem is, I've never dealt with cookies before and have no idea how to set one and then read it when a page is loaded. Anyone able to help me out on how to use jquery cookies to ensure the CSS height stays the same even after refreshes?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: Those are for javascript and HTML5 methods, I need help on using the jquery cookies plugin.

Comment: The plugin must have some kind of documentation. For example: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md

Comment: It's not very clear for me how to get it to work in my case

Comment: Please don't take this the negative way, but I don't think you're making an effort to understand how to make it work... Don't rely on stackoverflow to "outsource" your code. Come to us when you already tried. **Really** tried.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`jQuery.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin. Once you include it, you need to call it this way:

```
if (!$.cookie("height"))
    $.cookie("height", "297px");
```

And when you give a `changeHeight()` function, add this too:

```
function changeHeight(){
    $('#totalInfo').css('marginTop', '172px'); 
    $('.single #secondary-two #cart').css('maxHeight', '290px');
    $.cookie("height", "297px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kumar, could you please explain what does the ! mean in the first part of the answer? Also do I include this before or after the changeHeight function?

Comment: If the cookie is not set, initially, set the cookie. :) ps: Call me Praveen.

Comment: @user2028856 , `!` it's the logical not operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators). Basically, turns `false` into `true`, and `true` into `false`. Because `$.cookie()` returns false when the cookie is not set, using `!` will make the result `true` thus executing the `if` condition body. It's equivalent to `if ($.cookie("height") != false)`.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation @TelmoMarques!

Answer (score 1):

To create a cookie use :

```
$.cookie('height', heightValue);
```

To read it, use :

```
var height = $.cookie('height');
```

And to delete it, use :

```
$.cookie('height', null);
```

Comment: Consider adding a reference to the plugin used in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jquery_cookie()](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
$("#myid").on("click") {
function changeHeight(){
       $('#totalInfo').css('marginTop', '172px'); 
       $('.single #secondary-two #cart').css('maxHeight', '290px');
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
});

<button id="myid">Change height</button>
```

the_value means in this case:

you set the cookie like this:

```
$.cookie("foo", "somevalue");
```

Now you call the cookie like this:

```
alert($.cookie("foo"));
```

the output will be:

> somevalue

Comment: Where does `the_value` come from in this case?

Comment: See my simple example. about the value

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standard JavaScript, the following article should help:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

If you're using jQuery, it's even easier, using this plugin:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Comment: I do want to use it, but the problem is I have no idea how to use it in my case and how to read it back